# Dividir correctamente un SP con muchas consultas - Java - SQL - ORM Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

estoy queriendo pasar esta consulta sp de una DB en sql de un ejercicio y orientarlo a objetos con otro lenguaje, como java ,
Y me esta confundiendo el hecho de que en un UPDATE hay esta estructura de datos que me esta rompiendo en HQL:
Gracias

```
   @Transactional
   @Query("UPDATE Beneficio beneficio "
           
           + "SET beneficio.fechaDesde = (CASE WHEN bs.fechaDesde < bs.fechaHasta THEN bs.fechaDesde ELSE bs.fechaHasta END) "
           
           + "FROM Beneficio beneficio "
           + "INNER JOIN "
           //CODIGO"
           
           + "WHERE "
           //CODIGO



ERROR:


Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: FROM near line 1, column 459 [UPDATE
```

Comment: pero intentaste algo en alguno de esos lenguajes que nombras? que tiene que ver hibernate por ejemplo con c++? no me queda claro cual es tu consulta... como seria transformar un par de querys a un lenguaje orientado a objetos...

Comment: exacto,el obstaculo que tengo es como dividir la query en sql para trasladarlo a por ejemplo java y hql, ya que no se muy bien donde terminan y empiezan los 2 ultimos update

Comment: No entiendo muy bien tu pregunta, estas trabajando con Stored Procedure, no creo que en la parte de la base de datos importe mucho la estructura para interpretación de otros lenguajes. La forma de como lo llamas puede que cambie de un lenguaje a otro, pero eso es solo del lado del código dr tu aplicación.

Comment: No se si esto te sirva pero [aquí] (https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-stored-procedure/mysql-delimiter/) hay un tema para limitar en los Stored Procedure de MySQL puede ayudarte.

Comment: Yo sinceramente no entiendo el problema.. tu SP hace varias consultas.. no habria ningun problema en hacerlas todas por separado dentro de una transaccion.. cual es el problema particular que tuviste al traducirlas? al parecer son todas consultas por separado, pero sin saber que hace el SP completamente tampoco hay suficiente informacion...

Comment: Repite después de mí: La capa de persistencia no usa POO. :)   Si defines consultas individuales o un procedimiento almacenado, o un package con varios procedimientos y funciones, o alguna otra cosa, eso es estrategia en persistencia. No mezcles el modelo de datos con los patrones de diseño en otras capas de tu aplicación. Las entidades coinciden normalmente, pero no es claro qué es lo que necesitas hacer acá. No se entiende qué falló al separar cada instrucción SQL y ejecutarla desde tu programa

Comment: Hola a todos y gracias por su respuesta. Lo que hice despues de varias pruebas es separar el SP, ya que lo estoy migrando a hibernate con HQL. El problema es que TENGO UN UPDATE... SET... FROM... y me esta rompiendo porque no se si se puede hacer una actualizacion de registros y tambien un FROM. Gracias

Comment: Ahi reformule la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @Gonzalo como veo la pregunta y el error, el problema está en la construcción del UPDATE. Intente armar el UPDATE en una variable string, copie y pegue ese UPDATE construido y ejecútelo en su base de datos; para mí, es que hay palabras pegadas o falta una comilla o paréntesis = descarte si es un error en la construcción del UDPATE.